# InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified. Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, identityserver4

**Summary**

Attempting to publish a basic .NET Core React app with auth functionality I am receiving an error with IdentityServer. This is using dotnet new react --auth Individual, .Net Core 3.0 Preview5, and following the instructions [here](https://elanderson.net/2019/03/asp-net-core-3-react-template-with-auth/#comment-95427) and [here](https://elanderson.net/2019/07/deploy-asp-net-core-3-previews-to-azure-app-using-extensions/).

I've uploaded the PFX via the TLS/SSL settings. I've also ensured the certificate works on my dev environment, finding that `GetMyX509Certificate` returns the cert.

The code causing the issue seems to be in Configure in Startup.cs when running app.UseIdentityServer():

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...

        Log.Information("Configure - running app.Use: Authentication, IdentityServer");

       Log.Information("Configure - running app.Use: Authentication");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        Log.Information("Configure - running app.Use: IdentityServer");
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        //CODE DOESN'T MAKE IT HERE!!!
        Log.Information("Configure - running app.UseMvc");

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        Log.Information("Configure - running app.UseSpa");

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        Log.Information("Configure - Done!");
    }
```

**The Error**

Activating `ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = true`, I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified

Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string name)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
    System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
    System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
    System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
    System.Lazy<T>.get_Value()
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache<TOptions>.GetOrAdd(string name, Func<TOptions> createOptions)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>.Get(string name)
    Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager<TOptions>.get_Value()
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions+<>c.<AddClients>b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, string message, bool doThrow)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app)
    ReactWithAuth.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
    System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
        Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsCrypto.AddSigningCredential(IIdentityServerBuilder builder, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        Projects.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
        System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
        System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(object instance, IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader+ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder<TContainerBuilder>+<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<BuildStartupServicesFilterPipeline>g__RunPipeline|0(IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader+ConfigureServicesDelegateBuilder<TContainerBuilder>+<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<ConfigureServices>g__ConfigureServicesWithContainerConfiguration|0(IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

**Things I've tried**

There's not much out there in the way of solutions. The IdentityServer4 only talks about types in terms of [Grant Types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html), but this seems prior to that.

Comment: There are better way to deal with cert inside an app service, you may want to have a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-ssl-cert-load. you can also store your cert inside azure key vault.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to add the following settings into appsettings.json, within the "IdentityServer" brackets. This followed the "Clients" element:

```
  "IdentityServer": { 
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=**WHATEVER NAME YOU USED AS THE DISTINGUISHED SUBJECT FOR YOUR CERT**"
    }
```

This follows the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0#example-deploy-to-azure-websites). Note, that this was accomplished with a self-signed certificate created with OpenSSL following [this](https://benjii.me/2017/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-identity-server-azure/) post.

Comment: Hi just wondering did you also follow this part:"Using the certificate with Identity Server 4" in this article in your setup to get it working - https://benjii.me/2017/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-identity-server-azure/ ? Or just created the cert, uploaded to the private store and made sure your applicationsettings.json were correct?

Comment: From what I remember, when I was using IdentityServer, yes. When I stopped needing IS, however, I commented the cert functionality out. Hope that helps.

Comment: How would this look like if I'm using linux?

Comment: Use key type file for Azure AppService Linux like so: "Type": "File", "FilePath": "/var/ssl/private/THUMBPRINT.p12", "Password":  "". See here too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#load-certificate-in-linux-apps

Answer (score 44):

As you already answered - The solution is to add the following settings into appsettings.json, within the "IdentityServer" brackets. This followed the "Clients" element:

For File

```
 "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "C:\cert.pfx",
      "Password": "password123"
    }
  }
```

For Development (don't use in production obviously)

```
 "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

For Store

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Store",
    "StoreName": "My",
    "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
    "Name": "CN=MyApplication"
  }
}
```

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/aspnetcore/comments/bmq2n3/asp_net_core_3_angular_template_problem/)

Comment: Me and my colleagues were trying to get a proof of concept up and running so we just went with adding the `"Key":{"Type":"Development"}` to our identity server config. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "Project01": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above mentioned code , i am assuming that below line of coding is causing nullargument exception.

```
.AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

because the `**cert**` is null,which comes down to your method  `GetMyX509Certificate`

```
try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"HELLO! TRYING TO GET THE CERTIFICATE");
            return new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pfxFilePath), password, sFlags);
        }
        catch (PlatformNotSupportedException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"HELLO! {ex.Message}");
            if(sFlags.HasFlag(X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet))
            {
                return GetMyX509Certificate(pfxFilePath,password,X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            } else 
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"HELLO! {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
```

Since you code is not throwing `**PlatformNotSupportedException**` type of exception, for sure it will throwing Generic Exception which will be later catched by your last line

```
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"HELLO! {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
```

and from here you are returning null which internally giving you the actual error.

I don't understand why are you not able to use KUDU, but if i were you , i would suggest you to enable information logging using some logging library , e.g. File system logging  or Application insighy using custom telemetry.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Mohit, appreciate the response. I've updated the post - the cert seems to be working now that logging's started working (Kudu as well). The issue appears to be either with app.UseAuthentication() or app.UseIdentityServer();