# Use of LetsEncrypt certificate in Blazor Webassembly project published on ISS in Windows Server

Tags: iis, https, lets-encrypt, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-webassembly

I'm following this solution to use certificate for my Webassembly project.
[InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified. Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012001/invalidoperationexception-key-type-not-specified-microsoft-aspnetcore-apiautho)

If I use a self certificate it will works fine but I need of a C.A. certificate and I created it with Let's Encrypt.
How can I add LetsEncrypt certificate into appsettings.json? My new certificate hasn't password so the code below not works.

```
     "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "C:\cert.pfx",
      "Password": "password123"
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by creating a "new certificate with advanced options" instead of "create new certificate" through Let's Encrypt tool, in this way I can set the password required to use certificate in my .NET Core project.