# How to publish Blazor Web assembly with ASP.NET core hosting and identity auth app to azure App Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I want to host a Blazor Web assembly app with ASP.NET core hosting and the inbuilt identity authentication. I am a complete beginner and this is my first post so I apologize in advance for providing irrelevant or insufficient information. Please request additional information.

I created a so-called *File -> New -> Project* Blazor Web Assembly App with the ASP.NEC Core Hosted Checkbox Checked and selected **Individual User Accounts** under authentication and created the project. Started the app without debugging went to the registered age and registered and added migration from the browser button. Logged in and it worked fine.

Then I right-clicked on the server project and selected publish and followed the steps to publish on azure. It published successfully. But when I open the browser it gave me an error page "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure". Ran the app on the command line. It threw an error:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.Configure(ApiAuthorizationOptions options)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name) at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0()
> at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
> at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name) at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.b__7_1(IServiceProvider sp)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Type service, ILogger logger, String message, Boolean doThrow)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.Validate(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityServer(IApplicationBuilder app, IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options)
> at BlazorApp2.Server.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\Users\thari\source\repos\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\Server\Startup.cs:line 74
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at BlazorApp2.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\thari\source\repos\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\Server\Program.cs:line 18

Thereafter I published to a folder and run the .Server.exe file as administrator and got the exact same error.

This worked fine when Started within the Visual Studio IDE on both IIS Express and Kestrel.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you added authentication to your app, did any settings get added to appsettings.json or appsettings.development.json? If so, you probably need to reproduce them in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have not added your code here. I would suggest you to validate below settings to get this working:

Add the following settings into `appsettings.json`, within the `"IdentityServer"` brackets. This followed the `"Clients"` element:

**For File:**

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "C:\cert.pfx",
      "Password": "password123"
    }
  }
```

**For Development (don't use in production obviously):**

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  }
```

**For Store:**

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Store",
    "StoreName": "My",
    "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
    "Name": "CN=**WHATEVER NAME YOU USED AS THE DISTINGUISHED SUBJECT FOR YOUR CERT**"
  }
}
```

*Check out these threads for the same:*

- https://www.reddit.com/r/aspnetcore/comments/bmq2n3/asp_net_core_3_angular_template_problem/
- [InvalidOperationException: Key type not specified. Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ConfigureSigningCredentials.LoadKey()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012001/invalidoperationexception-key-type-not-specified-microsoft-aspnetcore-apiautho)

Comment: What are the values I should enter to the above parameters. Will it work if I just copy and paste one of the above except "For Development". Thanks for the response.

Comment: Pls check the links in the answer for more details.

Comment: Does this help?